# How to bring a selected (clicked on) bootstrap popover forward when multiple popovers are open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, svg, d3.js

I am using a bootstrap popover on svg elements in D3. Multiple popovers can be open at any given time. What I would like to know is how to, on clicking on a popover at the back, to force it to move to the front i.e. being focused on?

Is there any way to increment the z-index of an individual popover to move it forward manually?

Thanks.

Edit:

I have managed to create a fiddle using the suggested answer. The problem arises that, with using the global variable, it increments the z-index correctly on the most forward popover, but after bringing one to the front I am not able to access the others i.e. to even click the ones behind...so the click handler is not even being called. I'm thinking there is some type of layering going on. For example: If you look at the children nodes and click on one (the link in the title of the popover), then click on another one to semi-overlap the first open one - click the one behind and it will move forward. Click the one that is now behind and nothing happens:

jsfiddle.net/Sim1/YME9j/9

Is there an alternative to incrementing the z-index to bring a popover forward without hampering interaction with those that are behind it?

Comment: You could do this in a click handler.

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for the comment, can you possibly show me how to increment the z-index using code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this in a `click` handler:

```
element.on("click", function() {
  d3.select(this).attr("z-index", d3.select(this).attr("z-index") + 1);
})
```

As @AmeliaBR pointed out, this won't really work if you have more than one popover though as the `z-index` is only incremented by one. In a case like this, you could have a global variable that keeps track of the maximum `z-index` and use that.

Comment: Will this increase the z-index of the popover or the svg element?

Comment: SVG elements don't have a z-index. You can set the attribute just like any random XML attribute, but it won't have any effect.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work -- it's increasing the `z-index` on the clicked element, but not decreasing it on the other ones.  I would use a class to trigger the z-index change with CSS, and then it's easy to select the element that currently has that class and remove it:  `element.on("click", function() { d3.select(".popup.onTop").classed("onTop", false); d3.select(this).classed("onTop", true); })`.  Then the CSS would specify a z-index for the "onTop" class.

Comment: @RobertLongson: If I understood OP correctly, these are HTML popovers over an SVG chart.

Comment: @AmeliaBR: Your solution is definitely more elegant, but just increasing the `z-index` should work as well -- there's no need to decrement, you can just keep going.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff  But if I've clicked one pop-up twice, it will have z-index 2.  If I click another pop-up once, it will only have z-index of 1, so will still be behind.  In your version, the user has to keep clicking until it eventually makes its way to the front.  Another option would be to keep a global (or at least, exterior to the function) variable of "maxZ" that is incremented on every click, and use that to set the attribute: `var maxPopupZ=0; 
element.on("click", function() { 
  d3.select(this).attr("z-index", ++maxPopupZ);
}).`

Comment: Hi All! Many thanks for the discussion, I have been following it! I might have discovered an issue with continually incrementing z-indexes of popovers, although it may just be my stupidity: if you open two popovers and you select the behind one, it works perfectly to bring it to the front, but now if you want to select the one that is now behind, it is almost like there is an overlay layer that you can't access it because the other one's zindex is higher...almost like they are now not on the same layer so only the top layer can be accessed. Is there any other way to bring a popover forward?

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue with @AmeliaBR's suggestion of using a global variable.

Comment: Hi Lars, that is the solution I am using, the global variable, it increments correctly on the most forward popover, but after bringing one to the front I am not able to access the others i.e. to even click the ones behind...so the click handler is not even being called. I'm thinking there is some type of layering going on...is this incorrect to assume?

Comment: Can you show us a complete example? It sounds like the popovers in front are obscuring the ones in the back.

Comment: I will try and put an example together, my code is a little complex...so I will try and simplify it to focus on the popovers. Is there another way to bring a popover forward other than using the z-index?

Comment: Technically you could move the element to be the last one, but that's more complex.

Comment: Hi All, I have managed to created a fiddle for this to show what I meant by my previous comments. It is not at all elegant because I took most of the irrelevant code out. If you look at the children nodes and click on one (the link in the title of the popover), then click on another one to semi-overlap the first open one - click the one behind and it will move forward. Click the one that is now behind and nothing happens: http://jsfiddle.net/Sim1/YME9j/9/

Comment: The function that increments the z index doesn't seem to get called.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Does anyone know how to fix this? Many thanks for all the responses so far!