# How to change placement of Bootstrap popover in code on a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I am making use of the Bootstrap popover to appear on click of a "rect" in D3. Multiple popovers can be open at any one time, which is desired, but this introduces a problem of overlap.

Two possible solutions to this that I can think of are:

1. Use a button to allow the user to flip the popover to the opposite direction (at least).
2. Allow the user to drag a popover.

Unfortunately I am not sure how to attempt any of the above options. For option 1 I would need to be able to change the popover placement in code (which I have not seen other than the method to be able to initially place the popover) and for option 2 I would need to be able to move the popover away from it's attached item (which I am not sure is even possible).

What would be an ideal method of fixing overlap of multiple open Bootstrap popovers?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming this is still the same project as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147748/how-to-bring-a-selected-clicked-on-bootstrap-popover-forward-when-multiple-pop).  Is this fiddle still relevant or have you changed implementation? http://jsfiddle.net/Sim1/YME9j/9/

Comment: Hi Amelia, definitely still relevant, but I suppose without the issue of bringing the popover forward on selection as I have not yet been able to solve that issue yet (http://jsfiddle.net/Sim1/YME9j/12/). Thus, I need to at least get something working pertaining to the this question. Thanks for your assistance! Hopefully we can figure it out!

Comment: As far as I can tell, the "bootstrap" library is *only* used for initial position of the pop-ups, and deletes them when they are closed (versus making them invisible so they can be popped up again).  With that in mind, you could probably implement a [d3 drag behaviour](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior) on each pop-up each time it is called.  Search for demos.

Comment: Ok thanks, so the placement manipulation isn't possible. I will have a look for demos, thanks. I found this example: http://bootply.com/61825 but that works with dragging the object on which the popover is shown...and because I am using the partition layout I am not able to drag a "rect"  out of place.  If I could drag the popover itself away from the rect that it is attached to that would be ideal.